# SimpleDateFormat - how to prevent timezone being reformatted

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I am having issues with `SimpleDateFormat` changing the appearance of a `datetimestamp` when I parse a `String` and then format the resulting `Date`.

The code snippet below demonstrates the issue. Note: I know it seems futile to parse and then format the same date with the same `SimpleDateFormat`, but this is a contrived example just to demonstrate the principle:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
String dateStringToConvert = "2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00";
try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStringToConvert);
    String convertedDateString = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println("Wanted : " + dateStringToConvert);
    System.out.println("Actual : " + convertedDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output of this is as follows:

> Wanted : 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00
>
> Actual : 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000Z

As this date is to be used in an automated test to fill in a form, it is important that the format of the `datetimestamp` remains exactly the same after being parsed and formatted by the `SimpleDateFormat`, so I don't want it to remove the `-00:00` and add a `Z`.

It seems like a very simple problem, but I can't find any obvious answers.

Comment: There's no way of preserving whether the text is expressed as "+00:00", "-00:00" or "Z". That's not part of the parsed value. If you want to keep the same textual representation, just keep the string. It's also worth noting that "-00:00" actually has a very different meaning to "+00:00" in RFC 3339.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jon. My example above starting with a String probably confuses what I am asking. A far simpler way to phrase the question would simply be: How can I ensure that SimpleDateFormt.parse will return a String in format 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00 and not 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000Z? From your comment, perhaps the answer is that you simply can't do this?

Comment: I've just checked this example. I have another output: `Wanted : 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00
Actual : 2016-03-13T01:00:00.000+03:00` Probably result depend on the system settings? (I am in time zone UTC+3)

Comment: I'd be surprised (and worried) if *any* format (other than hard-coded) returned -00:00, given the odd meaning that has. Would +00:00 (for "no difference between this and UTC") be acceptable, or is your *intention* to use the -00:00 ("local time, we don't know the offset") meaning? If so, `Date` is unfortunate as it represents an instant in time...

Comment: Fundamentally, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, which makes it very hard to help - please clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. That's interesting and I guess it relates to you possibly being in a different timezone to me. In my above example, if I change the date from March to October (In UK where I am, March is BST, October is GMT), I too get different result:Wanted : 2016-10-12T22:00:00.000-00:00
Actual : 2016-10-12T23:00:00.000+01:00

Comment: Thanks Jon. Let me make my question crystal clear: "How can I use the parse method of SimpleDateFormat" to return a String that looks like this: 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00 and not like this 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000Z?"

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. It may not solve your problem, still I recommend you use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Comment: The answer is crystal clear: you ***can't*** use the `parse` method to get a `String` that looks like *anything*, because the `parse` method returns a `Date`, not a `String`.

Comment: All good comments. The newer java.time API was used instead (see accepted answer). This does the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid `SimpleDateFormat` can't help you. This class is poorly designed and very limited, not to mention all the problems it has: https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/

If you have Java 8, just use the `java.time` API. Not sure why you are converting a `String` to a `Date` just to convert it back to another `String`, but if you want the final result as a `String` with `-00:00` as offset, then you can do:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
  // offset, use "-00:00" when it's zero
  .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "-00:00")
  // create formatter, always work in UTC
  .toFormatter().withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String dateStringToConvert = "2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00";
Instant instant = fmt.parse(dateStringToConvert, Instant::from);
String result = fmt.format(instant);
System.out.println(result);
```

This will print:

> 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00

Comment: Very elegant use of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `appendOffset ` method. Main reservation may be that it will probably also output `-00:00` if the offset was `+00:00` in the original string.

Comment: I agree with Ole. This is a very elegant solution and it does exactly what I need. I know we're not really supposed to say thank you, but I'm an old fashioned kind of guy with old fashioned values, so I thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682138/simpledateformat-how-to-prevent-timezone-being-reformatted#comment84361871_48682138), there is no way around hardcoding this special requirement.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    String dateStringToConvert = "2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00";
    if (dateStringToConvert.endsWith("-00:00")) {
        formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'-00:00'")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
                .toFormatter();
    } else {
        formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx");
    }
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStringToConvert, formatter);
    String convertedDateString = dateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println("Wanted : " + dateStringToConvert);
    System.out.println("Actual : " + convertedDateString);
```

This prints

```
Wanted : 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00
Actual : 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00
```

As has also already been said, the offset of `-00:00` (negative zero) isn’t equivalent to zero offset, so it really isn’t correct at all to parse the string into an `OffsetDateTime` as I do. A correct version of the code would parse into a `LocalDateTime` in this case and format the `LocalDateTime` back using the same formatter. It would overall be a bit longer, on the other hand you would no longer need the `parseDefaulting` call.

I am using and warmly recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Because `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outmoded and have proven to be troublesome to work with in varying degrees. The modern API is so much nicer.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`

Comment: RFC2822 (and RFC3339) says in words: "-0000" also indicates Universal Time" but the local offset is unknown. I interprete this statement such that we can parse to `Instant`-like types (like `OffsetDateTime`) but not to `LocalDateTime`. See section 3.3 on [RFC2822](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822)

Comment: Another excellent application of java.time, which I am finding is making my life easier with all types of date/time manipulations. I'm grateful to you guys for the code examples. I will use the java.time api from now on.

Comment: **Beware…** The `-00:00` offset (a negative zero) is [*not* allowed is the ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC). Such a value is invalid. [*RFC 3339*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) is a profile of ISO 8601 yet overrides this rule is section 4.3 to define `-00:00` as meaning “an unknown offset”. That redefinition is of dubious value, being counter-intuitive, ambiguous, and completely unnecessary as ISO 8601 already defines the absence of any offset to mean unknown. So use `2016-03-12T22:00:00.000` rather than `2016-03-12T22:00:00.000-00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern) {
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer prefix, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
        StringBuffer finalStr = super.format(date, prefix, fieldPosition);
        finalStr = finalStr.insert(finalStr.length()-2, ':');
        finalStr = finalStr.deleteCharAt(finalStr.length() - 6);
        finalStr = finalStr.insert(finalStr.length() - 5, '-');
        return finalStr;
    };
};
System.out.println(df.format(yourDate));
```

Comment: I really appreciate this effort sindu. It almost does exactly what we want. It is returning this for me: 2016-03-12T22:00:00.000+00:00. The only difference is a '+' instead of the desired '-'. But this is a great starting point. Thank you.

Comment: @JonH I have edited the code to contain manipulate the - to +. Can you try this?

Comment: Yes, that does it sindhu - great work. In the end I went with the solution from sbs as it uses a newer API - java.time